# Changing color of weekday in DateCalendar in material ui

Tags: material-ui

```
  <DateCalendar
                  sx={{ p: 0, m: 0 }}
                  slotProps={{
                    calendarHeader: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    day: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    leftArrowIcon: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    rightArrowIcon: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    nextIconButton: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    switchViewIcon: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    previousIconButton: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    switchViewButton: { sx: { color: "white" } },
                    
                  }}
                />
```

[image]

Hello, through slotProps I can change color of every element of this calendar component apart from weekday names and year in year selector. How can I change it?